# Microk8s Cluster - Pods cannot reach nameserver/CoreDNS pod - No route to host

Tags: domain-name-system, kubernetes, calico, microk8s

**Disclaimer:**
This is my first question in ServerFault and I'm a complete noob.

I have the following set up:
remote VM, running **CentOS 7**, running **MicroK8s** (v1.28.3).
It's a **single-node cluster** so I have removed the taint from my Master Node and have already deployed my pods on it.

Upon startup, one of my pods (let's say "***problematic-pod***") tries to contact another one (let's call it "***target-pod***") but **does not seem able to reach the CoreDNS pod**. 
*Despite me calling it "*problematic-pod*", the same issue would occur with any of my pods (tested it), so it's not a pod-specific problem.*

My CoreDNS pod's ClusterIP is the default one (*10.152.183.10*), and I checked that it's up and running, having no errors in its logs.

Using a busybox named "debug-tools" to test it, running any of the following gives the same result,

`kubectl exec -it debug-tools -- nslookup target-pod`
`kubectl exec -it debug-tools -- nslookup target-pod.default.svc.cluster.local`
`kubectl exec -it debug-tools -- nslookup kubernetes.default`

which is:

> **nslookup: write to '10.152.183.10': No route to host**
> ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

I tried **disabling the firewall (stopped "*firewalld*") and everything worked.**

So I tried adding a rule with:
`firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="10.1.0.0/16" destination address="10.152.183.10" accept' --permanent`, 
which was created successfully, **but upon re-enabling *firewalld* my pod fails to reach 10.152.183.10 just like before**.
I checked that my pods' ClusterIPs indeed belong to said CIDR.

I am at my wits' end, any help will be appreciated and I will provide any and all info you require (sorry if I forgot to mention something important).